# mkdocs include with --8<-- not interpreted

Tags: include, code-snippets, mkdocs

I'm using mkdocs to create html web pages and snippets extension to fragment my master documents into small pieces. I have an incomprehensible bug:

In the file `file1.md` I made:

```
--8<--
includes/some_rep/fragment1.md
includes/some_rep/fragment2.md
...
--8<--
```

And all is ok... but in another `file2.md` i made:

```
--8<--
includes/other_rep/oher_fragment1.md
--8<--
```

And got a non interpreted output :(
Does some one experimented similar bug?

Comment: Same with `--8<--​ "test.md"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **[pymdownx.snippets](https://facelessuser.github.io/pymdown-extensions/extensions/snippets/)** in the markdown_extensions